# Why iPhone doesn't allow to auto play a video in the background of an html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why iPhone (both safari and chrome) doesn't allow auto-play a video inside of an html element? 
any workaround?

Comment: That was the way they made it I believe.

Comment: Speak in complete sentences, please.

Comment: _any workaround?_ I certainly hope not!

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's documentation:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

— https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Answer (score 1):

With the understanding that this is an educated guess only, I'd imagine that iOS disables auto-play for videos because the OS is focused on mobile devices.  iPhones, iPads, etc etc.  Users aren't going to want to download and run every single video on the web just because some idiot thought it funny to link to them on a page.  Not only is there limited memory on the device, but bandwidth is limited, and if you use too much of it expensive as well.